# how to get this jquery to work with Rails 4 and Turbolinks?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Rails 4.2.2 
gem turbolinks 
//= require turbolinks

I have had success using `$(document).on('page:change', function () { // });` but this script is being difficult. I do not use the jquery-turbolinks gem.

1. Unlike other scripts in my app, it will not work if I place it inside of the `assets/javascripts` folder. It only works if the script is placed in the `html.erb` view file.
2. It works correctly only the first time. Meaning, I want it run and then run again assigning new variable values, because all of the variable values will change after it is run the first time. Instead, when the function is initiated a second time (by clicking on `var craw = $('.glyphicon-chevron-right').last()`) it acts like it is being clicked on for the first time and adds the same page again and opens the same modal again because the variable values have not been updated.

   ```
   $(document).on('page:change', function () {
     var xyz = $('.nextinst').last().attr('href')
     var mod = $('.modal'+xzy)
     var turn = $('.pagination .next_page a').attr('href')    
     var craw = $('.glyphicon-chevron-right').last()
     $(craw).on('click', function() {
        if (!$(mod).size() > 0) {
          $.getScript(turn); 
        }
        setTimeout (function() {
         $(xyz).modal()
        }, 1000);
     });
   });
   ```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/18834209/2144445

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4: how to use $(document).ready() with turbo-links](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18770517/rails-4-how-to-use-document-ready-with-turbo-links)

Comment: Rails/Turbolinks versions?

Comment: @ArtOfCode I am currently using `Rails 4.2.2` and `gem 'turbolinks' = 2.3.0`

Comment: @inye `$(document).on('page:change', function () { // });` was the solution to the `$(document).ready()` problem. I have upgraded to `gem turbolinks = 5.0` using `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function)` but the script is still not running correctly. is there a way to force the script to reload the variables before it restarts?

Comment: @TimmyVonHeiss you have try with this gem https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the problem was in the java script itself and not related to Turbolinks. Either `$(document).on('page:change', function () { // });` with older version of Turbolink or `$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function)` with newer versions is the way to get jquery scripts to run with Turbolinks.